# Random wrong result from bitwise and operation in Java

Tags: java, jvm, jit

Following test fails for random i:

```
    @Test
    public void test() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
            boolean isTrue = and128(new byte[] {-1});

            if (!isTrue) {
                fail("broken: " + i + " " + isTrue);
                break;
            }
            clearCache();
        }
    }

    private void clearCache() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            and128(new byte[] {(byte) i});
        }
    }

    public static boolean and128(byte[] byteData) {
        return ((byteData[0] & 128) > 0);
    }
```

Because of randomness, I would blame Java Runtime. If I inline the method `and128`, I cannot reproduce the problem. Also if I just pass one byte instead of byte array, test passes.
I am using OpenJDK 14.0.2. Issue seems to be fixed in 15.0.2. It still seems to be present in 15.0.1 and I cannot find a bug that would correspond to this.

EDIT: I added this "clearCache" method that just runs on the side and makes bug easier to reproduce. I guess it prevents some java optimization.

Comment: check [fixes](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/15-0-2-bugfixes.html) for version 15.0.2 - maybe related to [JDK-8253191](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8253191) or was corrected by its correction - at least if I use `-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=3` I could not reproduce the error

Comment: @user15358848 seems to match, the issue is reproducible with JDK 15.0 but not with 15.0.2

Comment: I think we cannot be sure it's exactly that bug? First, it says it's for x86 architecture. Second, there are a few bugs mentioning C2, and `-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=3` just switches off C2. None of them sound related to my problem though, but I might be missing something.
In any case, I find it quite a bit scary, that java randomly produces wrong results.

Comment: @user15358848 this should be an answer.

Comment: I can confirm this is C2 bug [JDK-8253191](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8253191) - exactly the problem of masking byte values.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. @user15358848 Can you post your comment as and answer, so I can accept it?
Thanks a lot guys.